# Geting empty values when trying to read from Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with reading values from the Firebase database as I seem to not recieve any values at all. I'm trying to make a simple chat app using firebase and android. It seems I can however upload data to the database just fine...The app doesn't crash, it just displays one empty textview instead of 3 textviews each containing a message. Below is my code:

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etMessage;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMessage);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages");

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RVmessage);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

    }

    public void sendMessage(View v) {
        final String msgString = etMessage.getText().toString().trim();
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(msgString)) {
            final DatabaseReference newMsg = databaseReference.push();
            newMsg.child("content").setValue(msgString);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Message, MessageViewHolder> fbra = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessageViewHolder>(
                Message.class,
                R.layout.singlemessagelayout,
                MessageViewHolder.class,
                databaseReference
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder viewHolder, Message model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setMsg(model.getMsg());
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(fbra);
    }

    public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View view;

        public MessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
        }

        public void setMsg(String msg) {
            TextView tvMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
            tvMessage.setText(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tumex.chatapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout"
        android:id="@+id/RVmessage">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etMessage"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Message.java:

```
public class Message {
    private String msg;

    public Message() {

    }

    public Message(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return this.msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
}
```

simplemessagelayout.xml (layout for a single message):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tumex"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Hello everybody"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is what my Firebase DB looks like:

[image]

This is what my app looks like when I run it:

[image]

What needs to happen is it needs to show 3 messages something like:

```
Tumex
hi

Tumex
hi

Tumex
hi
```

if I need to post any gradle files please let me know and I will do so. Thank you in advance.

Comment: how are you getting `Tumex`?

Comment: I'm getting "tumex" by hardcoding the TextView `android:text="Tumex"`

Comment: What is the value of `msg` in this line of code: `tvMessage.setText(msg);`?

Comment: What it should be is "hi", but i think its empty

Answer (score 0):

I've never used FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, but looking at its [source code](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java) and this [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/e16784d9917e281196e47575d10b30c77f6f76c8/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/uidemo/database/ChatActivity.java) I think you either need to pass a Lifecycle owner to its constructor (if you are using Android Architecture Components) **or** call its startListening/stopListening methods.

If you use the Android Architecture Components and pass the activity to the constructor, it will handle all lifecycle events (like onStart, onPause, etc...) automagically.

If not, then you probably need to call startListening() on onStart() and stopListening() on onStop().

Answer (score 0):

Feeling like a dummy right now...the problem was that in my `simplemessagelayout.xml` the `android:layout_height="match_parent">` should have been `android:layout_height="wrap_content">` so the messages were there I just couldn't see them because every message had a screen-sized empty while space at the end.